# Why Tomcat support Hibernate?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlet-container

Why Tomcat support Hibernate? Hibernate is implementation of JPA, but Tomcat doesn't support Java EE. So why we can use Hibernate in Tomcat?

Answer (score 5):

Tomcat doesn't *provide* Java EE support (meaning it doesn't contain implementations of the various parts of Java EE, except for the servlet part, obviously), but that doesn't mean it cannot run code like Hibernate that *does provide* the implementation of JPA and doesn't have other Java EE dependencies that cannot be met by either Tomcat itself or other libraries.

Comment: ok, so why Websphere 6.x and 7.x don't support JPA 2.0 without Feature Packs?

Comment: Because they don't bundle Hibernate but use another implementation? I'm not even sure JPA 2.0 existed when WAS 6 was released. And that doesn't stop you from using Hibernate in your application, instead of depending on the provided implementation. What's the connection with the initial question, anyway?

Comment: Connection with initial question is: if WAS 7 doesn't provide JPA 2.0 implementation, _also as Tomcat_, so it's mean that I can run JPA 2.0 (Hibernate) on WAS with the same result as on Tomcat? I.e. I get absolutely _same_ restrictions and benefits when using HIbernate, independently in which server I run it?